# Question on interpretation of a sentence involving the phrase "each and every"

Tags: phrase-meaning, pronouns, quantifiers

I am trying to read a book and the following is the quote:

> "Christian belief in Communion of Saints means that in heaven, we will have deep, intimate, strong, loving and fulfilling relationship with God and with each and every angel and heavenly human."

Does the quote mean that in heaven, we will have deep, intimate, strong, loving and fulfilling relationship **with God, with each and every angel, AND with each and every heavenly human**?

Thank you,

Comment: In your exact context it's unavoidable that *with each and every* must be assumed to modify both nouns (it's a normal aspect of English to "delete" the repeated element in ***and with each and every** heavenly human*). You can tell this by considering what happens if you assume it only applies to *angel*. Remove the reference to angels, and you'd be left with *...relationship with God and with heavenly human*, which is clearly not a valid usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does mean what you think it means.

I think the passage should read

> fulfilling relationship**s** with God, and with each and every angel and heavenly human

since "each and every" singles out, individually, the angels and heavenly humans

The passage should also possibly read

> belief in **the** Communion of Saints